# How to check user credentials in AZURE AD when acquired token using appId/appSecret (adal4j)?

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, adal4j

I've created webapp (not native) in Azure AD. I have java code (adal4j) that
acquire token using appId/appSecret credentials:

```
    String clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String clientSecret = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";

    String resourceUrl = "https://graph.windows.net";
    String authorityUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz/oauth2/authorize";
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    Optional<UserInfo> userInfo = Optional.empty();

    try {

        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl, false, executorService);

        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = authContext.acquireToken(resourceUrl, new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret), null);
        AuthenticationResult result = future.get();
    }
```

Now I would like to check if specified user/password combination is in Azure AD and if yes then get First and Last name of this user.
Is it possible to do this usinq acquired token ? How to write such code using adal4j ?

Comment: Tell us what exactly you want to achieve and why. As stated your question speaks of something similar to `I would like to do a brute-force attack to identify valid credentials`. And your actions will be interpreted as such by the thread protection mechanisms in Azure AD, regardless your, probably good, intent.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're really trying to do is sign in a user and get their first/last name. As the comment said, the pattern suggested is not a valid one and would represent a security issue. Additionally, the use for *clientId* and *clientSecret* is not exactly for user credentials, but for app credentials. This is used for flows without user interaction for service/api applications, and doesn't sound like what you'll want.

Now, to achieve this you'll be using the [*OpenID Connect* protocol](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html).  To simplify what will happen, your app (upon user trying to sign in) will redirect to the Microsoft sign in page (https://login.microsoftonline.com), enter their credentials and fulfill any other authorization requirements, consent to your app, and then redirected back. When they come back, your app will receive an `ID Token` which can be validated and used to get information about the user that has just sign in. During this time, Azure AD / Microsoft will also set a cookie on the browser so the user will get SSO across their account.

In terms of how to achieve this, I recommend following the [ADAL4J Code Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect). This will get your app an `ID Token`, and also an Access/Refresh token that you can use to call the [Microsoft Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.io).  This API can also get you information about the user (basic profile info), but also their Office365, Intune, and Windows data.